# pythonic way to fix index out of range in sliding window

Tags: python, loops, indexing

I am doing this leetcode question using sliding window, and I realized I was getting the IndexError because the maximum j (= idx+1) could get is out of range. I was wondering if there is a graceful way to fix it?

Link: https://leetcode.com/problems/best-time-to-buy-and-sell-stock-ii/

Problem statement:

```
You are given an array prices where prices[i] is the price of a given stock on the ith day. Find the maximum profit you can achieve. You may complete as many transactions as you like (i.e., buy one and sell one share of the stock multiple times).
```

Example input and output:

```
Input: prices = [7,1,5,3,6,4]
Output: 7
Explanation: Buy on day 2 (price = 1) and sell on day 3 (price = 5), profit = 5-1 = 4. Then buy on day 4 (price = 3) and sell on day 5 (price = 6), profit = 6-3 = 3.
```

Here is my code:

```
class Solution:
def maxProfit(self, prices: List[int]) -> int:
   
    totalProfit = 0
    currentProfit = 0
    
    for idx, x in enumerate(prices):
      
        j = idx+1
        
        while prices[j] > prices[idx] and prices[j] > prices[j-1]:
            
            currentProfit = prices[j] - prices[idx]
            totalProfit += currentProfit
            
            j += 1
 
    return totalProfit
```

Error message:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
while prices[j] > prices[idx] and prices[j] > prices[j-1]:
```

Edit: as suggested by @Prune I break the loop when j exceeds boundary before entering the next iteration. It works for the sample input but I haven't tested it with corner cases. Lets discuss if there is room for improvement!

Here is the updated code:

```
class Solution:
def maxProfit(self, prices: List[int]) -> int:
   
    totalProfit = 0
    currentProfit = 0
    
    for idx, x in enumerate(prices): 
      
        j = idx+1
        
        if j == len(prices): # boundary: break before entering loop
            break
        
        elif prices[j] > prices[idx] and prices[j] > prices[j-1]: # when continue to increase, enter loop

            currentProfit = prices[j] - prices[idx] # return value
            totalProfit += currentProfit # sum and return
      
            j += 1 #increase window size
            
    return totalProfit
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: In general, the graceful way to fix this is to compute the correct bounds before you enter the loop; iterate only as far as you can legally go.  This is basic algebra; exactly where are you stuck?  Since you failed to provide the full error message and a proper trace, we'd have to properly instrument and run your code to get the needed information.  This is your task.

Comment: you do NOT need a class, a simple function is enough as you do not hold any state in this code. Are you a Java dev by chance?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
from typing import List

def max_profit(prices: List[int]) -> int:
    profit = 0
    if len(prices) > 1: 
        bought_at = prices[0]
        for price in prices[1:]: 
            if bought_at and bought_at < price:
                print(f'sell at: {price} - bought at : {bought_at}')
                profit += (price - bought_at)
                bought_at = 0
            else:
                bought_at = price
    return profit     

result = max_profit([7,1,5,3,6,4])
print(f'profit: {result}')
```

Output:

```
$ python3 so.py
sell at: 5 - bought at : 1
sell at: 6 - bought at : 3
profit: 7
```

Comment: Interesting solution! I tried it with a different input [1,2,3,4,5] but it returned 2 where the expected answer is 4.

Comment: Tbh I’m not sure I understand exactly when we’re supposed to buy or sell ;-)

Comment: I think it is like there will be a continuous rise in the prices, only sell on the last day of it, and buy in when there is a drop in price